# Get ID of currently logged in FB user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

I've created an app in FB, i've set a path of page as its canvas page,users on my website can invite their facebook friends,friends gets notification for invite when they click on notification they are redirecting to my website, on page(ie one i've mentioned in canvas page)  i am redirecting user to my website using this

```
window.top.location.href='mywebsite'
```

Now i want that when friend click on the notfication i get the facebook ID of that friend.
Is this possible?How can i get the ID of that friend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need the user who accepts the request to authorise your app before you can determine their user ID